# Deinit method is not called in Xcode 10 Beta 6 playground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10

I was exploring memory management concept and found
`deinit` method is not calling in **Xcode 10 beta 6 playground**. Initially I thought may be some problem in code. Then I test same code in Xcode 9.4.1 playground and Xcode 10 beta 6 sample app everything is working as expected (deinit method is called). Is it bug in **Xcode 10 beta 6 playground** or anything else? I am using apple developer's code-

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    weak var apartment: Apartment?

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        print("\(name) is being initialized")
    }

    deinit { print("\(name) is being deinitialized") }
}

class Apartment {
    let unit: String
    weak var tenant: Person?

    init(unit: String) { self.unit = unit
        print("Apartment \(unit) is being initialized")
    }
    deinit { print("Apartment \(unit) is being deinitialized") }
}

do {
    var john: Person?
    var unit4A: Apartment?
    john = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
    unit4A = Apartment(unit: "4A")

    john!.apartment = unit4A
    unit4A!.tenant = john
    john = nil 
    unit4A = nil
}
```

Comment: Playground is not a good place to test ARC features, as it holds strong reference to some intermediate values. Test your code with Command Line Tool project and see what happens.

Comment: @OOPer OP said it works in Xcode10 App AND in Xcode9.4 playground. Dunno whether its documented(and so a bug, which may be worth reporting) or undocumented(they don’t care).

Comment: @Deepak They could see it as a regression so it might be worth a short bugreport.

Comment: @Purpose, thanks, in fact I was missing that OP has tested in an app. But, still the same. Playground, REPL or LLDB is not a good place to test ARC features.

Comment: @Purpose, OOPer, thanks for your response, I hope in regression apple team will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems to still be present in Xcode 10.0 (10A255). I have playground with the following code:

```
class Person {
    var name: String

    func buy(car: Car) {
        car.owner = self
    }

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        print("Person \(name) is initalized")
    }

    deinit {
        print("Person \(name) is being deinitialized")
    }
}


class Car {
    let model: String
    weak var owner: Person?

    init(model: String) {
        self.model = model
        print("Car \(model) is initialized")
    }

    deinit {
        print("Car \(model) is being deinitialized")
    }
}

print("===== before do =====")
do {
    print("    ---- do begin -----")
    let johnny = Person(name: "John")
    let porsche = Car(model: "Carrera4")
    johnny.buy(car: porsche)
    print("    ---- do end -----")
}
print("===== after do =====")
```

In Xcode 9.4.1 both Car's and Person's deinit are executed, but in Xcode 10.0 (10A255) the Person's deinit method is not executed.

The same code inside a test macOS project works as expected (both deinit executed) in Xcode 9.4.1 as well as Xcode 10.0 (10A255)